# Problem with internet connection --- service NetworkManager restart does not help 21.04

Tags: networking

I have a problem with my internet connection.
Since Monday, there is a question mark on the wifi icon AND I don't have internet connection.
I try a lot of things but nothing works:

The router is classic "SFR Box 8". All the LEDs are on. It's wifi. All my devices except the laptop in question can connect to my wifi router and have internet access.
I'm with Ubuntu 21.04
To solve the problem I already tried

`sudo service NetworkManager restart`

This was not works.

I also tried to go to Settings > Privacy > Connectivity Checking and set it OFF.
Then, the question mark on wifi icon disappeared, so the wifi icon is back to normal as I had the internet connection.
But when I try to use Firefox I don't have internet connection.
Also,
`ping google.com`
doesn't work.
So I set Connectivity Checking back to ON.

When I try to connect  my laptop to another SSID it's work.
So I try to "Forget this network" but when I try to connect it again same issue.

Then I try
`journalctl -u NetworkManager>file`
to see if there is any warn and I found this

`août 25 11:52:22 boubou-Inspiron-5402 NetworkManager[4471]: <warn>  [1629885142.9964] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist`

`août 25 11:52:23 boubou-Inspiron-5402 NetworkManager[4471]: <warn>  [1629885143.2825] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate`

`août 25 11:52:23 boubou-Inspiron-5402 NetworkManager[4471]: <warn>  [1629885143.4094] sup-iface[d33d15215efdd0d9,12,wlp43s0]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What are the links in your question for?

Comment: to show what I try

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
I download network-manager from ubuntu archive then
`apt-get remove --purge network-manager`
and
`apt-get install --reintall network-manager`